# withCredentials Causing Web API Auth To Be Called Twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, http-headers

the problem I am having is when I send `withCredentials: true` to my Web API and return `Unauthorized`, the function is called again which then returns with the browser login form.  I just want the function to run once with simple `401` returned.

For example, in my controller:

```
[Route("search")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetDeposit([FromUri] DepositSearchFilter filter)
{
    return Unauthorized();
}
```

If I set a break-point then `return Unauthorized()` is executed twice and after the second execution the browser display the login form.  **However**, if I replace Unauthorized with `Forbidden()`, then the function only runs once and returns.

Additionally, I create my own `AuthorizeAttribute` to handle the Authentication Token being sent in a cookie.  When I add the header [`ValidateToken]` the same thing happens inside of the custom Attribute.  If I return `Unauthorized()` then `OnAuthorization` is called again and the browser displays the login form.  But If I return Forbidden inside the custom Attribute it runs once.

```
public class ValidateToken : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        CookieHeaderValue headers = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetCookies().FirstOrDefault();

        CookieState authCookie = headers.Cookies.Where(p => p.Name == "AUTH-TOKEN").FirstOrDefault();

        actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authCookie.Value);

        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
        //if (!base.IsAuthorized(actionContext))
        //{
        //    HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
        //}
    }

    //protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    //{
        //actionContext.Response = actionContext.ControllerContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Unauthorized");
    //}
}
```

So, when I send `withCredentials` then any code that returns `Unauthorized` runs twice and then the login form in the browser is displayed.  I need the code to run **only once** and return just a 401.

For the browser login form showing, I am returning a `401` along with

```
WWW-Authenticate:Bearer
WWW-Authenticate:NTLM
WWW-Authenticate:Negotiate
```

The Web API does not return `Basic` or `Digest`.  I have other Web API calls in which the response returns the same thing but the `Unauthorized` code does not execute twice and the login form is not shown.  The difference is **`withCredentials`** is not sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure **Anonymous Authentication** is **enabled** and **Windows Authentication** is **disabled**.  That should remove `NTLM` and `Negotiate`

```
<IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>enabled</IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>
<IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>disabled</IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>
```